# Subclassing stringstream gives "0x401bad ABC" instead of "Foo ABC"

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A : public std::stringstream {
        public:
                A() {}
                ~A() { std::cout << str().c_str() << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    A() << "Foo" << std::string(" ABC");
}
```

I was expecting the program to print:

```
Foo ABC
```

instead of

```
0x401bad ABC
```

Why **0x401bad ABC** is printed?

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

Comment: Clang and GCC give me your expected result. Please provide the compiler/library details.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: You are lucky to get that nice pointer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator<<` is implemented in two parts:

- Overloads for character data are free functions.
- Other overloads are members of `std::ostream`.

We're concerned about the [first one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for that string literal. As you can see in the link, all of the overloads take a non-const reference to `std::ostream`. This means your temporary `A()` doesn't fit. Thus, the [member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) taking `const void*` is used.

C++11 adds support for an rvalue reference to `std::ostream` for a generic `const T &` argument, which accepts your temporary object, so the string literal is printed when compiling with C++11.